# loop overwrite in R output the last value

Tags: r

```
y<-list() #?????? STUCK!!!!HERE:overwrite problems
for (i in 1:2^N){
    for (j in 1:N){
    comstate[1:N,] = comN[i,]#spoint<-comN[i,]
    tcomstate=t(comstate)`#need transpose "comstate" to ensure col stands for the component state
    tcomstate[j,j]=(1-comN[i,j])#diag(tcomstate)<-(1-comN[i,j])}}
    y[[i]] <- which( colSums(t(comN)==tcomstate[j,])==ncol(comN) )}}
    y
```

I am stuck in an overwrite problem in R loop. `y` output should be four values (eg. 11,7,1,4) , but it only has one value (4), I tried `y<-list()` and `array()`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot reproduce your code (without comstate etc.), I created a small example with what would be a solution. You should add an empty vector (temp_vector in example) to temporarily store the solution of:

```
 which( colSums(t(comN)==tcomstate[j,])==ncol(comN) )
```

Since now you are indeed only storing the last value in y. Furthermore, I believe that y should be outside the for loop with j and only inside the for loop of i.

```
y=list()
N=3
for (i in 1:2^N){
  temp_vector=c() 
  for (j in 1:N){
    ad=c(ad,j)} 
    y[[i]]=ad}
```